# Setting up Angular Directives

Tags: angularjs

I'm making an angular app that needs to have modules that can be reused across multiple pages.

I've made a directive that successfully creates a menu list but at the moment it has to be registered as part of the ng-app it's going to sit inside, like this:

```
angular.module('home', [])
    .directive('Picks', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: 'HTML/templateURL.html'
    };
});
```

Is the idea of Angular that my whole site is built on the one page/ng-app wrapper? Or is their a way that I can make this Picks directive work without defining it for each ng-app it will sit inside?

Hope that all makes sense!

Comment: You need to register your directives with every `ng-app` you define, but typically this would be only one app on a single page. Of course there is no reason why you cannot have multiple independent apps on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In development mode prefer using a separate js file for directives. If the directive depends on nothing from the home app, it can be reinjected in other app as well.

```
//file component.js with directive usually alongside their Controllers
var someModule = angular.module('business', []);

someModule.directive('Picks', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: 'HTML/templateURL.html'
    };
});

/*file homepage.js inject the component module as a dependency*/
angular.module('home',['business']);

/*file main.js another app*/
angular.module('myApp', ['business']);


<!-- index.html -->
<html ng-app="home">
...
<script src="component.js"></script>
<script src="homepage.js"></script>
</html>
<!-- eventually concat and minified for pre production, so it doesn t matter
how you organized it
-->
```

In practice some directives use some service/factory alot. So they ends up in the same module. This mean grouping modules by feature rather than by type.
It's a matter of choice.

Comment: Thanks Mehery, that makes sense. In my uneducated terms: Register the directive inside it's own angular.module, then inject that module as a dependency into other modules when needed.